# Glossy iOS doesn't conform to protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to integrate [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) to do json parsing but I get lots of non sense errors.

I installed it with pod install and I experienced followings:

- First when I import it, I got
  : `Cannot import underlying modules glossy`, I don't know how, but after copy pasting the example from GlossExample project in github repo it disappeared.
- Second if I use: `struct Repo: Glossy` I get error that `Repo doesn't conform to protocols Decodable and Encodable` but the code is pasted from the example and there exist the methods `init?(json: JSON)` and `func toJSON() -> JSON?`
- Then I tried to use `struct Repo: Decodable` and having this function for decoder:

  ```
  init?(json: JSON) {
  let repoId: Int = "id" <~~ json
  ```

I get following error: 
`35: Binary operator '<~~' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'JSON'`

- Last I said OK, I won't use overloaded operators but the normal `Decoder` class:

  ```
  init?(json: JSON) {
    self.repoId = Decoder.decodeURL("id")(json)
  }
  ```

I got: 
`Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'JSON' (aka 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>')`

Your helps and answers are welcome!

Comment: can you provide an example project where you're receiving these issues?

Comment: @HarlanKellaway I get these even in the example project you provided in the github after doing pod install (https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss/tree/develop/GlossExample) My Xcode was 7.2 and after having these errors I updated to 7.2.1 but nothing changed

Comment: perhaps it is that 7.2 is being used - that comes with Swift 2.2 and Gloss was last updated with Swift 2.1. I'll add a task for myself to update. If the functionality Gloss provides is needed before that happens, a different library should be used.

Comment: okay, @HarlanKellaway Thank you for quick response

Answer (score 1):

> - First when I import it, I got : `Cannot import underlying modules glossy`, I don't know how, but after copy pasting the example from GlossExample project in github repo it disappeared.

This is an issue that happens in Xcode with a few frameworks, but simply cleaning the code or directly running it usually gets rid of the warning. Otherwise it may have to do with using an older build of Xcode.

> Second if I use: `struct Repo: Glossy` I get error that `Repo doesn't conform to protocols Decodable and Encodable` but the code is pasted from the example and there exist the methods `init?(json: JSON)` and `func toJSON() -> JSON?`

This means that your `struct` doesn't conform to both protocols. From the [Glossy declaration](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss/blob/develop/Sources/Gloss/Gloss.swift):

```
/**
Convenience protocol for objects that can be
translated from and to JSON
*/
public protocol Glossy: Decodable, Encodable { }
```

So the Glossy protocol inherits both Decodable and Encodable, which means that you need to implement the protocol functions for both protocols, and not just `toJSON() -> JSON?`.

> Then I tried to use `struct Repo: Decodable` and having this function for decoder: ...

You need to first declare the constant in the struct, and in the init deserialise the JSON and set the value to the constant:

```
struct Repo: Decodable {
    let repoId: Int

    init?(json: JSON) {
        guard let repoId: Int = "id" <~~ json { else return nil }

        self.repoId = repoId
    }
}
```